# What is a permutation representation in regard to group actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I have read the definition of a permutation representation from Dummit and Foote, and Wiki, but I don't understand.

Can I please have an example? I get the impression that we can write a group action normally as:

$$G\times X\to X, (g,x)\mapsto g\cdot x$$

Or we can write it as a permutation representation, i.e. a group action does:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\\sigma(1)&\sigma(2)&\sigma(3)&\sigma(4)\end{pmatrix}$$

Is that all a permutation representation refers to?

Comment: Here is an example. The group of rotations ($\cong Z_3$) acts on the set $V$ of vertices (label them $1,2,3$) of an equilateral triangle -- one would often just say that $Z_3$ acts on $V$ by rotations. Then we get a mapping $\pi$ from $Z_3$ to $S(V)$, which is just $S_3$ using the labels. $\pi$ takes the $0^\circ$ rotation to $e$ (it fixes all vertices) the $120^\circ$ rotation to the permutation $(1 \, 2 \, 3)$, and the $240^\circ$ rotation to $(1 \, 3 \, 2)$. $\pi$ is a group homomorphism -- it's easy to check this here, but by the way group actions are defined you always get a homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBrevik that makes sense, I appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A permutation representation is the same thing as a group action, basically.  If a group $G$ acts on a set $X$, then the action gives a homomorphism from $G$ to the group of permutations on $X$, which is the definition of a permutation representation of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: Does this apply too, to uncountable groups; specifically Lie groups?

Comment: @MSIS Yes.  Why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

With your definition of a $G$-action on a set $X$, you get as a lemma that such an action gives rise to a homomorphism:
$$\varphi\colon G\to S_X$$
defined by:
$$\varphi_g(x):= g\cdot x$$
Both the membership $\varphi_g\in S_X$ and the operation-preserving property $\varphi_{gh}=\varphi_g\varphi_h$ follow from the defining properties of a group action. Therefore, every image element $\varphi_g$ *is* a permutation of (=bijection on) the set $X$.

[ Incidentally, you might (and most people actually do) define "action" precisely such a homomorphism, and prove as a lemma that this gives rise to a map $G\times X\to X$ via $g\cdot x:=\varphi_g(x)$, which fulfils 1) $e\cdot x=x$ and 2) $g\cdot (h\cdot x)=(gh)\cdot x$ ]

If the set $X$ is finite of cardinal $n$, then every image element $\varphi_g$ admits the two-line representation:
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1&\dots&x_n\\\varphi_g(x_1)&\dots&\varphi_g(x_n)\end{pmatrix}$$
which is not yet precisely what you have written. To complete the job, take any bijection:
$$f\colon \{1,\dots,n\}\to X$$
and define the map:
$$\psi_f\colon S_X\to S_n$$
by:
$$\tau\mapsto f^{-1}\tau f$$
This is an isomorphism, and the "permutation representation" of $g\in G$ is the permutation (now of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$!) defined by:
$$\sigma_g:=(\psi_f\varphi)(g)$$
whose two-line representation is now truly:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&\dots&n\\\sigma_g(1)&\dots&\sigma_g(n)\end{pmatrix}$$